# Lambda NodeJS function not firing when executed from website but works fine in console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is my first attempt at creating a lambda function using NodeJS. The proper behavior is to first send email then second open the `Contact_Success.html` page.

The function does not send email when it's invoked via API Gateway from my website, but it does open the `Contact_Success.html` page.

When tested inside the AWS console either from the API Gateway test or the Lambda Dev console, emails *do* get sent.

Here is the code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const querystring = require('querystring');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

exports.handler = function(evt, context, callback) {
    // Our raw request body will be in evt.body.
    const params = querystring.parse(evt.body);

    // Our field from the request.
    const first_name = params['first_name'];
    const last_name = params['last_name'];
    const emailaddr = params['email'];
    const telephone = params['telephone'];
    const comments = params['comments'];

    var eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["blahblah@blahblah.com"]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                  //  Data: first_name 
                  Data: first_name + " " + last_name + " at " + emailaddr + " phone:" + telephone + " post:" + comments
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: "BlaBlah Inquirty"
            }
        },
        Source: ‘blahblah@blahblah.com'
    };


      // Create the promise and SES service object
  const sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
    .sendEmail(eParams)
    .promise();

  // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
  sendPromise
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.MessageId);
    // Generate HTML.
      const html = `<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://blahblah.com/Contact_Success.html"</script>`;
    // Return HTML as the result.
     callback(null, html);
     context.done(null, "Success");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err, err.stack);
    // Generate HTML.
      const html = `<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://blahblah.com/Contact_Error.html"</script>`;
    // Return HTML as the result.
      callback(null, html);
      context.done(null, "Failed");
    });
};
```

Comment: As suggested by @AJ, please check the CloudWatch logs (and in general monitoring, to make sure the function got triggered through API Gateway). Then you're down to old school debugging, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I would start debugging this by looking at the logs in cloudWatch

Comment: Well I got this working.  Seemed I lacked permission for execution using the role I setup.  Once I added fuel SES access it worked.  It let to another strangulations behavior but that is outside of this the scope of this request.  In any event this code seems to work fine when posting to the API gateway, with proper permissions set using IAM roles.  Thanks again!